Why does the SERIALIZABLE transaction isolation level not guarantee point-in-time views of data?
I have been told that if your transaction consists of multiple statements, then the SNAPSHOT transaction isolation level is the only way to guarantee consistent point-in-time views of data. Why is the SERIALIZABLE transaction isolation level inadequate for this task? By design, the locks that SERIALIZABLE holds are very tight.
I think the gap in my understanding is that I am unsure when SERIALIZABLE takes its very tight locks. A script like the below will likely be very helpful in finding what I am missing.
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

SELECT TOP (1) * FROM [Hit_Me_First];

WAITFOR DELAY '00:02:00';  

SELECT TOP (1) * FROM [Hit_Me_Second];

COMMIT;


People always seem to want to understand isolation levels in terms of locks.
This is somewhat strange because isolation levels are generally not defined by locking, rather by concurrency phenomena* one might experience at each level.
Some products happen to implement some isolation levels using locking, but this isn't true for all levels or products. For example, SQL Server has both lock-based and versioning-based implementations for the read committed isolation level.
Even serializable isolation is implemented in SQL Server without locking when you use the in-memory OLTP (Hekaton) storage engine. PostgreSQL also implements serializable using a versioning scheme by the way.

I have been told that if your transaction consists of multiple statements, then the SNAPSHOT transaction isolation level is the only way to guarantee consistent point-in-time views of data.

Snapshot isolation does guarantee you see only committed data as it was at the start of the transaction. The start of the transaction is the first time you access versioned data within the transaction, not when you issue BEGIN TRAN.
Serializable also provides a consistent view of the data as it was at a point in time, but that point in time is generally not the start of the transaction. To understand this, consider the SQL Standard definition (emphasis added):

A serializable execution is defined to be an execution of the operations of concurrently executing SQL-transactions that produces the same effect as some serial execution of those same SQL-transactions. A serial execution is one in which each SQL-transaction executes to completion before the next SQL-transaction begins.

If the effects are the same as if all transactions ran serially, in some order, clearly you will see only committed data as it was when your transaction ran serially (i.e. with no concurrent activity). The crucial difference is you cannot know exactly what that schedule of serial executions was.
If you really must think about this through the locking implementation, consider that SQL Server takes sufficient locks to ensure all data needed by your transaction does not change after it is read. Further, no new data that would be seen by your transaction if it were re-run can be added until your transaction ends (no 'phantoms').
Through that lens, the point in time view is from when the last lock needed by your transaction was acquired to the end of your transaction. For convenience, you could choose this to mean the time the transaction ended.
Again, I emphasise that this is a consequence of an implementation decision. It could change, in principle. I would encourage you to understand concurrency through the logical guarantees provided and concurrency effects avoided.
For more, see my article The Serializable Isolation Level and the rest of the series for other isolation levels, including snapshot isolation.

* Any effect due to concurrency that would not occur if the transaction ran alone

The issue here is with the definition of "point in time".
In SQL Server, SERIALIZABLE guarantees that you will see consistent data as it was at some moment during the life of the transaction.
This will not necessarily be the moment when the transaction began, since in your example, the locks could be placed on Hit_Me_First, but Hit_Me_Second can continue to vary during the middle waiting time.
Consistency is guaranteed by the fact that Hit_Me_First cannot vary after it has been queried, so however Hit_Me_Second varies after Hit_Me_First is locked, you are ultimately going to get a consistent snapshot of both tables at the moment when Hit_Me_Second is finally queried.
(Deadlock and cancellation of the transaction, of course, is also a possible outcome of this algorithm in general - so you are in fact guaranteed to get either consistent results, or  no results at all).
Now, SNAPSHOT isolation works differently in that all data is read as it was at the moment the transaction began (rather than at some other moment during the life of the transaction), and there cannot be deadlock between transactions which purely read data.
The downside of SNAPSHOT is that it does not guarantee true serializable execution for transactions which write.
It's worth mentioning in passing that in Oracle, SERIALIZABLE is synonymous with SNAPSHOT, due to what many regard as sloppiness in the ANSI standard definition, and Oracle does not have a true serializable isolation mode.
The common-sense definition of serializable is that "the effect of two transactions scheduled to execute concurrently, are guaranteed to be the same as if they were executed on some fully serial schedule", but this is not how the ANSI standard does define it.
The term referring to the isolation mode which uses snapshots and also accords with the common-sense definition of serializable, is called "serializable snapshot isolation" (SSI), and amongst the major database engines I'm only aware of Postgres having this mode.

SNAPSHOT doesn't even guarantee serializability for read-only transactions. See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/333902.
